# Google Form onFormSubmit not triggering

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have an issue with a google form I am working on. I set up the trigger as seen below.

[image]

When the form is submitted an alert box should pop up with information taken from a google sheet.(The form is linked to the sheet)

When I run the code from the script editor it shows the popup in the form, but the trigger never trips when I submit a response to the form.

I have tried:

1. - deleting trigger
   - creating a new version of the script
   - adding trigger back
2. change trigger to TimeDriven and still no trigger
3. change the script to standalone with the same trigger

Not sure what the issue is since I can execute the code manually.

Comment: Share your code snippet.

Comment: A dialog box can't be shown in "View" mode of a Google Form.  When you are running the code from the script editor, the pop-up that you are seeing is probably in the "Edit" mode of the Google Form.  "On Form Submit" doesn't run from Edit mode.  If you are trying to get something to display to the user after they submit the Form, then your only option is the confirmation message: `FormApp.getActiveForm().setConfirmationMessage(message)`

Comment: Amit:
var String = "Remaining Budget\n"
  for (var i = 0; i < 29; i++)
  {
    if(i > 29)
      i = -1
    if(i == 0)
      String = String + Cat[i] + ":" + In[i] + "\n";
    else
      String = String + Cat[i] + ": " + Rem[i] + "\n";
  }
  FormApp.getActiveForm().setConfirmationMessage(String)

Sandy: You are correct I am seeing the dialog box in the edit window. I tried the confirmation message approach you said and I am still not seeing the message I want.

Correction. I am seeing the message when I run the form and not from a preview. Thank you Sandy for that input.

Comment: Form Submit, event change, and time-driven triggers don't run in an instance that is guaranteed to have a UI attached to it. So attempting to use a UI class to display information is not useful for those cases. Some installed triggers (like the spreadsheet `edit` and `change` ones) do have this guarantee satisfied, with the precondition that they don't activate for programmatic changes.

Comment: By using the setConfirmationMessage(String) I am able to get the message I want, but the data it is pulling is not the most up to date. it is pulling the info before the submit. I want the submitted data to be included in the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sandy Good states:

> A dialog box can't be shown in "View" mode of a Google Form. When you are running the code from the script editor, the pop-up that you are seeing is probably in the "Edit" mode of the Google Form. "On Form Submit" doesn't run from Edit mode. If you are trying to get something to display to the user after they submit the Form, then your only option is the confirmation message: `FormApp.getActiveForm().setConfirmationMessage(message)`

Using `.setConfimrationMessage(message)` works for what I want to do. (Give a list of sheet cells when the response of the form is submitted)